# Using SQL, would it be possible to retrieve a field from a different table (using a stored procedure) using a foreign key referencing that table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Film` with the primary key `FilmID`, and a column called `CoverImage`. In a separate table `History`, I inserted `FilmID` as a foreign key. I wrote a stored procedure `select_CoverImage_By_FilmID` to retrieve an image by its `FilmID`. What would FROM need to reference in the stored procedure?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Film] 
(
    [FilmID]     [INT] IDENTITY(1000000, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CoverImage] [NVARCHAR](200) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_FilmID] PRIMARY KEY([FilmID] ASC)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Film] ([CoverImage], [FilmID])
VALUES ('\Notflix\Notflix_DB\CoverImages\SOTD-C.jpg', 1)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ViewingHistory]
(
    [UserAccountID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [FilmID] [INT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_UserAccountID_] PRIMARY KEY ([UserAccountID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fk_Film#_FilmID]  
        FOREIGN KEY([FilmID]) REFERENCES [Film](FilmID) 
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ViewingHistory] ([FilmID])
VALUES (1)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [select_CoverImage_By_FilmID]
    (@FilmID [INT])
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        [CoverImage],
        [FilmID]
    FROM  
        [Film] 
    WHERE
        [FilmID] = @FilmID
END;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear what your question is. Does the stored procedure you show give an error, or not do what you want? Can you show us the current output and what you expected / wanted?

Comment: @DaultonJohnSchilling . . . Stored procedures cannot be referenced in a `FROM` clause.  Perhaps you really want a user-defined table function.